# how to plot 3d graph for x^2 - y^2 = 1?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

How to plot 3 dimensional graph for x^2 - y^2 = 1? I am already using it and I only can plot in 2 dimensional graph. Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: (1) What do you mean by "I am already using it"? (2) What kind of 3D plot are you looking for? Your equation is the equation of one-dimensional curve that you can plot in 2 dimensions. Where does 3D come in? (3) In other words, please provide more details.

Comment: Try `ContourPlot3D`.

Answer (score 3):

In Mathematica tongue `x^2 - y^2 = 1` is pronounced as

```
x^2 - y^2 == 1
```

> x^2-y^2=1

It is a hyperbola, Wolfram|Alpha is verry helpfull for first findings,

[image]

The Documentation Center (hit F1) is helpfull as well, see [Function Visualization](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/FunctionVisualization.html),

```
Plot3D[x^2 - y^2 == 1, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot3D[x^2 - y^2 == 1, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

```
RegionPlot3D[x^2 - y^2 - 1 > 0, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

And to get the Wolfram|Alpha Plot:

```
ContourPlot[x^2 - y^2 == 1, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, Axes -> True, 
Frame -> False, AxesLabel -> {x, y}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Taking Rahul's idea:

```
ContourPlot3D[x^2 - y^2 == 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[{u,Sqrt[u^2-1],v},{u,-2,2},{v,-2,2}],
 ParametricPlot3D[{u,-Sqrt[u^2-1],v},{u,-2,2},{v,-2,2}]
]
```